# Prelaunch task build terminated with exit code 1

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, launch-configuration

I'm trying to learn how to create method libraries but whenever I run my program a little pop-up window (with a surprisingly basic Windows graphical interface, post-update) shows up with the message "PreLaunch task 'Build' terminated with exit code 1."

I click on "Show error" and in the "problems" tab I see the message "No problems in the workspace so far."

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here are my launch configurations...

[launch configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbcN6.png)

[image: launch configurations]

[launch configurations 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIYxK.png)

[image: launch configurations 2/2]

Here is a screenshot of that pop-up window bearing the message.

[pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFeZY.png)

[image: pop-up window]

Also, I'm not sure if this is related but I noticed that this stuff started happening after I moved the .NET SDK files to another folder, and also when the debugging shortcut command stopped working.

Comment: The configuration file as text, not images, would be more helpful.

Comment: I had the same problem and I had to download the version that specified in the console error. And then follow the steps in this link.. make sure to open a new command prompt to execute the commands https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the same error after renaming my project.  The problems was that in my **task.json** file, the arguments were referencing my previous project *csproj* file.

## task.json (old)

```html
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyOldProject.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

`

I changed the csproj file name to the current project's name it worked without any errors.

Answer (score 8):

The problem might be in the tasks.json file since the error is 
"**PreLaunch task 'Build'**" (that's in the tasks.json file).

With the latest vscode update all the warnings in the console were treated as errors and since I removed this line of configuration **"problemMatcher": "$msCompile"** (in tasks.json) it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In mac ensure the VSCode can detect .NET

Try doing a symbolic link.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/

Also, ensure that terminal.integrated.inheritEnv is true in VSCode settings.

Answer (score 0):

In dotnet the Main() method needs to be a static. Try changing your definition from

`public void main()`

to

`public static void Main()`

and see if that helps. This microsoft doc will give you some more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/

Comment: Thanks!  I changed the definition, but the problem still seems to be persisting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your Launch.json, in your [First Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbcN6.png) , in .Net Core Launch (web) section , in Program attribute, you should write the framework you are using and your project name instead of the default text.

for example `netstandard2.0` and `mylibrary.dll`

And you can remove the web configuration if you are not going to write asp code.

Also you can delete Tasks.json because you can build and test your whole project by F5  by configuring your Launch.json like this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/parsalotfy/10a466c0681fc14bdd86debee7e9789d)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see any update is required or an extension is needed 
I searched for ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.13 
and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is my first time to use Visual Studio Code IDE to create a C# program, I just follow the simple guideline to test the first case "Hello world". unfortunately, I got the same issue, so I had traced every step to look at what's wrong with me, the result was I didn't close my "Dotnet run Environment"

All my steps:
Step 1:using command line to create "Dotnet environment" 
[image]
[image]

Step 2:using VS Code IDE to open this folder "MyWebsite" and I got the error message after ran it 
[image]
[image]

Step 3: closing "command line" and VS Code is okay now 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

6/16/2023~

Hi, I got the same problem, reading online I found something related to the launch.js file. After just only removing a line it works:

"preLaunchTask": "build",

Comment: The date tag is not necessary since the date is visible anyways. Also the code should be formatted. Otherwise your answer is a bit short, but fine. Please fix the mentioned points and then I am fine with it.