# Visual Studio Code: How to configure 'dotnet' not to show warnings when compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

OK. I am in .NET Core and using Visual Studio Code on a Mac machine. Now, whenever I run my C# project then Visual Studio Code shows this annoying message:

> The preLaunch task 'build' terminated with exit code 1

It shows me the option to click on a button called *"Show problems"*. When I click on this button, it only shows the warning messages.

Now, if it was errors then it's OK to see this message. But the fact that it shows this message every time there are warnings (which to me is OK). That is very annoying. Is there a way I can configure Visual Studio Code to not show these messages on things like warnings?

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590601/prelaunch-task-build-terminated-with-exit-code-1?

Answer (score 5):

In order to disable warnings, you should add `-nowarn` to `args` in the `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject.csproj",
                "-nowarn" // here
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question above, there are only warnings that I can see in  terminal. What I am saying is that if there is anyway to configure VS Code that it does not show this message for trivial reasons like warnings?

Comment: @WorkBee So your topic should be : How to cinfigure _dotnet_ not to show warnings when compiling, Because vscode just runs the code in task.json.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a problem with your `task.json` file. Check the arguments of the file and make sure the build is pointing at the right location:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```